Can Conda recipes clone AND SAVE a git repository?
Our team has many laboratory computers on which we have to install a heterogeneous set of homemade software. To simplify things, say there's one git repository in pure Python, one in Python plus Cython, and one in Go. It's been a big pain telling our non-expert users how to install all the dependencies, the three git repos, and then build and install the results. When it works, they basically never update. And if they do, they might update only one repo or two, ending in an incompatible state.
My dream is to create a Conda channel, one Conda recipe for each package, and finally a meta-recipe that simply depends on the other three packages. Then the user could install all the packages with one command, and later update all with a similar one.
Here's the weird part of the dream: I would really love for the installation to preserve the git repository, so that when needed an expert can develop on that computer, pushing back to GitHub as needed. Is this possible, or difficult, or impossible? Is Conda capable of cloning git repositories and preserving them for future development?
It sounds like the now-deprecated conda develop might have been helpful here, but it's now deprecated! I could use the scary pip install -e . under Conda, but even that doesn't leave the git repository anywhere safe--it's subject to cleaning, nor does it help with the Golang project.
Am I asking for something that is fundamentally incompatible with Conda's philosophy?
If I'm planning a fundamentally non-Conda approach, then I guess a solution could be:

For normal users, use Conda to install from source. The repos are not exposed.

When needed by experts, use git clone to install a development copy. How to keep its compiled files from interfering with Conda sounds like a nightmare, but maybe it's not so bad.


